# Does Android Google App Invite send emails to none gmail address?

Tags: android, google-app-invites

I'm testing Google App Invite beta.

1. Emails sent to gmail addresses work.
2. Emails sent to a none gmail addresses are rejected.

**Is this suppose to happen?**

Answer (score 0):

Tested latest version of App Invites Beta and it works with all kinds of emails. I have it in production on one of my apps and it performs fine.
App Invites actually sends emails from your behalf, so you can find them in "Sent" folder of your Gmail account. Also don't forget to check in spam folder of the receiver.

Comment: I keep getting this error below: Mail Delivery Subsystem <mailer-daemon@googlemail.com> Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:Technical details of permanent failure:
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain The error that the other server returned was:
552 5.2.0 erwA1s00K3vQdcH01 - erwA1s00K3vQdcH01rwBLG This message has been rejected due to content judged to be spam by the internet community IB212- Why is this happening?

Comment: It seams that your mail server rejects the message for thinking it as a "spam". You can try to contact support of this mail server. Also try with different mail address on other server to see if the problem exists.